# How to init a component only when its tag is at `*ngIf=true`?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

**Update:**
Günter Zöchbauer provided a very acceptable answer that works perfectly (and thank you!). But I still have a question to check if what I am doing is the correct way of getting the result I seek. Context is given below.
What I expect with my custom tag on the parent view, is that when the `*ngIf` condition is false, the component is not loaded at all (or maybe most part of it). Is it normal that even if it is not in the DOM (because the condition is false), it is still loaded? Is there a better way to embed components' templates (and the logic of their class) into a parent component's template?

## Original post

I am new to Angular 2 and so far I'm having much fun developing a small song track metadata application based on the Spotify API.

**TL;DR:** How to init a component only when its corresponding HTML tag (defined with the `selector` property of `@Component`) if `*ngIf="true"`?

---

But of course I'm facing difficulties! I have this component, `TrackDetailComponent`, in the template of which I would like to include 2 other components. On clicking on a button, it would switch from one inner component to the other.
Here is how the template looks like (note that I only have developed one of the two inner components for now, so I used a placeholder in stead of the second one):

```html
<div id="view">
    <tig-track-info *ngIf="childView == TrackDetailView.InfoView" [track]="track"></tig-track-info>
    <p *ngIf="childView == TrackDetailView.LyricsView">Here go the lyrics</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, my inner component (named `TrackInfoComponent`) has an input parameter. Here is an excerpt of that component:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: "tig-track-info",
    templateUrl: "app/components/track-info/track-info.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["app/components/track-info/track-info.component.css",
                "app/shared/animations.css"]
})
export class TrackInfoComponent implements OnInit {
    private _trackId: string = null;
    @Input() 
    track: Track = null;
    previewAudio: any = null; // The Audio object is not yet defined in TypeScript
    albumArtworkLoaded: boolean = false;
    ...
}
```

My real problem is not embedding the `TrackInfoComponent` inside the other one, but it is to sync them. The `TrackDetailComponent` calls an API asynchronously and then initializes the `track` property. But `TrackInfoComponent` also needs that `track` to be initialized in order to do its job or else I get a null reference exception (which is logical).

I tried setting the child component data in the `ngOnInit()` and setting the `*ngIf` of its parent's template to true only when the `track` is ready but it seems that `ngOnInit()` is called right away, even if the DOM element `tig-track-info` is not display with `*ngIf`.

I guess I could use events or my own init method in the child component, to call only when I'm ready, but I would like to know if there is a better way to do it using the Angular 2 component lifecycle hooks or any other method recommanded for that. Does anyone have any idea about that?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Have you tried ngAfterViewInit or ngAfterViewChecked?

Comment: It doesn't work. I also tried AfterViewInit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [OnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html) which is called whenever an `@Input()` property value is changed by a template binding `[track]="..."

```
  export class TrackInfoComponent implements OnChanges {
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      if(this.track) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Perfect! So would that be the recommanded way to achieve what I want to do? I updated my original post to elaborate on this question. (I will mark your post as answer when my extra question will be answered :-) )

Comment: `ngIf` adds/removes the element completely. If the condition becomes `false` the component is removed and destroyed. When it becomes `true` a new component instance is created and added. Is this what you want to know? When you don't want thus behavior use `[hidden]="someExpression"` to only show/hide instrad of `add/remove`

Comment: I know this behavior and that's why I don't understand why the child component is instanciated although the `*ngIf`Condition is false at first.

Comment: I'm sure if the `ngIf` condition doesn't become `true` at any point, the component will not be instantiated at all. Maybe it's instantiated by other means. Can you provide a Plunker to reproduce (https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I changed my mind about that part, so I my UI differently. I don't have the code anymore. So let's close this topic. Thank you for your time and help :-)

Comment: Thanks, that one pushed me over the 100k hurdle :-)

Answer (score 0):

1) first step

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Add ChangeDetectorRef in your code

2) second step

```
constructor(private changeDetector : ChangeDetectorRef){
}
```

3) whenever you there is change in your *ngIf="condition" ie condition becomes true, then
you can call

```
  if(true==condition){
     this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  }
```

4) This will render your html template.

You can try this,if it works for you.